# Situation with `restrict` keyword/attribute in C++ standard

Tags: c++, standards, c++20, restrict-qualifier

In short, [`restrict`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) is supposed to tell the compiler that the pointers cannot point into the same memory location. Which is very useful for, say, function arguments and further compiler optimization. In scientific computing, `restrict` is very widely used.

Currently, `restrict` keyword is only a part of C99, but not a part of C++. We [know that a lot of C++ compilers support `__restrict__` as an extension. This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776283/2452869) also talks in detail about what `restrict` and `__restrict__` do.

Now, the discussion in the aforementioned question happened a long time ago and does not talk about C++17, C++20, nor plans for future standards. I found [n3988 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3988.pdf) that discusses `restrict`-like aliases in C++, complexities with richer syntaxis in C++, and potential remedies.

According to the IBM blog (2014), [n3988 was encouraged for future work](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/c_14_is_ratified_the_view_from_the_june_2014_c_standard_meeting?lang=en).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22724980/2452869) talks about the history of `restrict` and C++ without anything conclusive regarding the actual implementation and mentions the papers I already listed or [the one mentioned in the comments (p1296)](https://wg21.link/p1296).

I was not able to find anything beyond that on the plans of supporting `restrict` in the upcoming C++ (as far as I know, it's not a part of C++17). It seems like a very useful functionality, so I wonder

- if I missed something in terms of proposals/discussion?
- is there other information on the `restrict` usage in C++?
- are there alternative ways to make the compiler optimizations (allowed by `__restrict__`) possible by using only "standard" functionality?

Comment: Related to your last question: https://wg21.link/p1296

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing like C’s `restrict` is in even C++20.  The [paper already mentioned](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1296r0.pdf) was well-received at a preliminary presentation in November 2018, perhaps because it avoids the critical difficulty with a qualifier—that no one, even in C, understands how it interacts with the rest of the type system.  Part of this is because adding `restrict` doesn’t change the meaning of any one pointer, but affects its relationship with some set of other pointers (whose membership is not well-specified) based on what arithmetic is performed with them later.  Another part is because C++ allows so many operations with types: what would `std::vector<T *restrict>` mean, and what would be the type of indexing a `std::vector<T> &restrict`?

Just what practical optimization opportunity will be offered by such a contract-based approach is not yet clear; there are still many unanswered questions about contracts and optimization in general.