# why std::vector and std::string use "for" loop to copy or move elements?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20

why std::vector and std::string use "for" loop to copy or move elements?Wouldn't this be bad for performance?

Recently, I am reading the stl source code of libcxx in [llvm-libcxx](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/libcxx).But I found that the std::vector and std::string use "for" loop to copy or move elements in the container. Wouldn't this be bad for performance compared to processing with some faster functions while the element is basic type, for example memcpy and memmove.
Here is the code in std::vector

```
LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY static _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_SINCE_CXX20 char_type*       copy(char_type* __s1, const char_type* __s2, size_t __n) {
    if (!__libcpp_is_constant_evaluated()) {
        _LIBCPP_ASSERT(__s2 < __s1 || __s2 >= __s1+__n, "char_traits::copy overlapped range");
    }
    char_type* __r = __s1;
    for (; __n; --__n, ++__s1, ++__s2)
        assign(*__s1, *__s2);
    return __r;
}
```

I want to know why not implement a specialized version vector or string to accelerate the processing.Initially, I thought the compiler would optimize this part of code, but it doesn't.
I have test the performance between for-loop and `memcpy`(I known which is accelerated by SSE or AVX instructions).

Here is the test code:

```
void func(char *p1, char *p2, int len) {
    memcpy(p1, p2, len);
}

void func(char *p1, char *p2, int len, int f) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        p1[i] = p2[i];
    }
}
```

The Result is as follows

```
//(memcpy) loop for 100000000000 times, cost time 305 us
//(for-loop) loop for 100000000000 times, cost time 1967 us
```

I use compiler explorer to see the disassembly code. Obviously the compiler doesn't optimize. The compile flag "-Os" is common in project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stROE.png)

**Edit:**
I have retest using char_traits::copy.The performance is similar to the memcpy version.
And the char_traits does have a specific version char_traits using the std::copy to copy elements.Sorry for not reading very carefully.
I got it, Thank you guys.

Comment: Have you checked whether the compiler already performs such optimization when the code is compiled? I would think that rather likely.

Comment: memcpy can only be used if a class is trivially copyable. For almost all classes it will be necessary to call constructors too.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl I have considerred about this.It seems that the compiler(MSVC, default setting) doesn't do the optimization.

Comment: Also note that the test comparion is between memcpy and array indexing. The original library code doesn't do indexing. (Apples and oranges :-)

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer I known that. So I said "why not implement a specialized version vector template or string to accelerate the processing". I think it's worth. After all, vector<int> often appears in my code.

Comment: *"(MSVC, default setting)*" The default setting doesn't do *any* optimizations. Also, libcxx is specifically written for clang, not for MSVC.

Comment: @BoP I added a picture of clang disassembly

Comment: Wouldn't it be bad for performance?   Hard to say.   With modern hardware and modern compilers - even more so modern compilers when building with optimisation - programmer intuition about what is good or bad for performance is pretty inaccurate.    Even more so for small bits of code, such as a loop copying data. The only way to know for sure would be to examine what the compiler emits and (another thing needing skill to get right) to measure/profile program performance.   I wouldn't accept your assertion of "bad for performance" without evidence.

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/cYxYf9qqz)

Answer (score 5):

### About the test code/benchmark:

##### Replacing the copy-loop with memcpy is incorrect

Considering your test code:

```cpp
void func(char *p1, char *p2, int len, int) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        p1[i] = p2[i];
    }
}
```

A c++ compiler replacing this loop with a simple `memcpy` would be non-standard compliant, because:

- The compiler must emit code that works *as intended* even if `p1` and `p2` are overlapping buffers (in more pedantic terms: `p1[i]` and `p2[j]` can alias the same object, even under the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)).
- Using `memcpy` on 2 overlapping buffers is **undefined behaviour** anyways.
- Given the c++ aliasing rules, `func` is in fact extremely different from [std::memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), or even [std::memmove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) (which explicitly allows overlapping buffers) in the overlapping case.

Consider the following program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void func2(char * p1, char * p2, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        p1[i] = p2[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string foobar = "0123456789";
    func2(foobar.data() + 3, foobar.data(), foobar.size() - 3);
    std::cout << foobar;
}
```

[Live demo(godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/9xr7MGhPz)

Any standard-compliant c++ compiler must print `0120120120`.

##### Bypassing the aliasing rule

The C language has the [restrict](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) keyword to indicate that the compiler can safely assume that an argument/variable doesn't alias anything else. [`restrict` is not standardized in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724980/why-is-the-restrict-keyword-not-part-of-c), but `__restrict` is an extension available on modern versions of gcc, clang, and MSVC:

```cpp
void func2(char * __restrict p1, char * __restrict p2, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        p1[i] = p2[i];
    }
}
```

[Live demo(godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/MbYW5nzzx)

`gcc & clang -O2`, and `MSVC /O2` currently all replace this function by a memcpy.

---

**Edit:**

### About the std::copy implementation:

To answer the primary question, gcc/clang/MSVC compilers are able to optimize a copy-loop into a `memcpy` if they can safely assume there is no aliasing between the source and the destination.

For copy between containers (std::vector / std::string / other) containing trivially copyable objects, your standard library probably provides this guarantee in some way: either in a standard way using the strict aliasing rules, or by using some compiler built-ins. For example, [_LIBCPP_ASSERT](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/b6af251be5ef891b7ccad153f678d3e02e525da9/libcxx/include/__assert#L42) in the original question internally emits a `__builtin_assume` for the compiler.

Comment: The question is about `std::copy`, not about your `func`.

Comment: @n.m. To be fair, the OP has 2 quite independent questions. 1) Why is std::copy implemented that way 2) Why the compiler doesn't seem to optimize copy loop in `func`. I'll edit for point 1 later.

Comment: The answers are "because it can" and "it does", in that order. Note the function *in the question* asserts if the ranges overlap. Your function doesn't, bit the question is not about your function.

Comment: I\m sorry, the question does ask why a function like `func` is not optimised, I missed it.

Comment: I don't agree with the statement **Replacing the copy-loop with `memcpy` is incorrect**. The standard requires that [the ranges do not overlap](https://eel.is/c++draft/char.traits.require#tab:char.traits.req), thus the replacing with `memcpy()` is always correct.

Comment: @273K This statement is for the loop in OP's `func(char*,char*,int,int)` used for the benchmark. Your quote only describe a precondition for `std::char_traits<*>::copy(...)`, it can't be assumed by the compiler for an unrelated function.

Answer (score 2):

> why std::vector and std::string use "for" loop to copy or move elements?

They don't always. You are looking at the wrong specialization.

> Wouldn't this be bad for performance

It would be, but fortunately [the compilers use `memmove` or `memcpy` when appropriate](https://godbolt.org/z/zE7qvqd9q)

> I want to know why not implement a specialized version vector or string

The compilers in fact implement specialized versions of algorithms like `std::copy`. There is no need to specialize `std::string` or `std::vector`.

> Obviously the compiler doesn't optimize

Your function does not behave like `memcpy` or `memmove` when source and destination ranges overlap, so the compiler cannot possibly optimize it down to one of these functions. `std::copy` and `std::char_traits::copy` do behave like `memcpy` when the type of the elements is trivially-copied, so the compilers can and often do optimize them down.

Compilers cannot always optimize an explicit loop down to `memcpy` even if said loop is in fact equivalent to `memcpy`. Library writers help compilers by providing appropriate specializations.

--

Note, by the standard `char_traits` with cannot be instantiated with user-defined types, but some compilers do implement this possibility anyway.